# URL parameter format in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5

I hve a Laravel 5.2 application. I have a route where I receive a parameter called ID by GET method. The format of the ID is giving me some problems, an ID is formed like:

```
Somecharacter%40otherThing.somethingelse
```

Sending the ID as above gives me "File not found" in the browser, but if I delete the `%` or the `.` everything works fine, it's like they cannot coexist in the URL. The route in Routes.php file is:

```
Route::get('generateFile/{action}/{id?}',array('as'=>'generateFile','uses'=>'MyController@generate'))->where('id', '(.*)');
```

So, I'm starting to believe that I have to modify the `where` clause in the route, but I don't know what exactly should I put to make it accept a parameter.

Comment: what happen if you remove the `where` ?

Comment: Or maybe you could do a `base64_encode` when you send the request and in the controller retreive the ID by using `base64_decode` ?

Comment: @Roadirsh thank you!! It wasn't a crazy idea, I made it and it works (y)

Comment: `Somecharacter%40otherThing.somethingelse` works for me. However, `char%a` does not work so, try to `urlencode` your strings and make sure `%` is encoded - with `%25`

Answer (score 0):

Just pass id with encryption urlencode

```
urlencode(\Crypt::encrypt(id));
```

get the id back using

```
urldecode(\Crypt::decrypt(id));
```